# search a file with bitbucket rest api (v1.0)

Tags: bitbucket-api

How can I search a file with a name on bitbucket via rest API? (v1.0)

It seems there is an [endpoint](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.16.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idm8297049152) useful to get the file but there is no one to search and find the file(s) with name.

Answer (score 3):

I found this option for Bitbucket Server:

Call `POST` request for `https://<bitbucket_server>/rest/search/latest/search` endpoint:

**Option 1:** with parameters `{"query":"\"<file_name_with_extension>\"","entities":{"code":{"start":1,"limit":10}}}`

OR

**Option 2:** with parameters `{"query":"<part_of_file_name> ext:<file_extension>","entities":{"code":{"start":1,"limit":10}}}`

where `start` is page number, `limit` is number of the results on the page.

In my case I used Option 2, because I needed to search file containing some keyword in the name.

This request returns JSON.

**UPD 17th Feb:** mentioned above search happens in default branches only. So, if you need to search in all branches, then there is option to go through all files in each branch.